# Apache config file. Redirect permanent gives 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I am changing my domain from foo.com to foobar.org. I used a `Redirect permanent` in my apache config file, and then restarted apache. When I try to access the old domain foo.com, I get a 403 error.

This is what my apache config file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  #ServerAlias www.foo.com
  #ServerAdmin sysadmin@foo.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.foobar.org/

  DocumentRoot /path/to/project/foo/web
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  # CustomLog with format nickname
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
  CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/apache2/%Y%m.foo.access.log" common

  LogLevel notice
  ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/apache2/%Y%m.foo.errors.log"

  <Directory />
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
  </Directory>

  <Files ~ "^\.ht">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
  </Files>

  <Directory /path/to/project/foo/web>
      Options -Indexes -Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All

      RewriteEngine On

      # We check if the .html version is here (cacheing)
      RewriteRule  ^$ index.html [QSA]
      RewriteRule  ^([^.])$ $1.html [QSA]
      RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

      # No, so we redirect to our front end controller
      RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path/to/project/foo/web/uploads>
     Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Includes
     AllowOverride None
     php_flag engine off
  </Directory>


  Alias /sf /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/data/web/sf
  <Directory /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/data/web/sf>

#  Alias /sf /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.4.19/data/web/sf
#  <Directory /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.4.19/data/web/sf>
      Options -Indexes -Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone spot what I may be doing wrong?. The site foobar.org does exist so I don't know why this error occurs - help?

Comment: This configuration file is on foo.com and not on foobar.org, right?Then why don't you remove every thing but the redirect permanent inside this .htaccess? Can you access `www.foobar.org` without getting a 403?

Comment: mod_alias is activated, isn't it? ("Redirect" = mod_alias stuff, "RewriteXY" = mod_rewrite stuff).

Comment: @j0k: I don't understand your statement. I have removed everything else from the config file. the only two directives are `ServerName` and the `Redirect` directive. However, I still get a 403 when I try to access foo.com, but typing foobar.org works ... ?!

Comment: @initall: Yes. mod_alias is activated. I don't understand the rest of your comment though, please clarify.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli like j0k said, comment out `Redirect permanent / http://www.foobar.org/` and see if you get your old site to display.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos: I'm not sure I understand the logic behind your suggestion. If I remove the `Redirect permanent` directive, then I am back to the old config file, which (obviously) does work - I have been using the site (with the old config) for a little over 2 years now.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli We wanted to know and have you verify something else was not causing issues and indeed adding the Redirect caused the 404. Now turn off  `RewriteEngine On` inside `<Directory /path/to/project/foo/web>` to see if that is clashing with something.